# Как сделать, чтобы сначала шло имя, а потом значение?

Tags: python

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = requests.get('https://minfin.com.ua/currency/crypto/')
soup = BeautifulSoup(url.content, 'html.parser')
names = soup.findAll('div', class_='sc-18qu8it-11 hZgTBs')
for namess in names:
    print(namess.text)

price = soup.findAll('div', class_='sc-18qu8it-3 fygJIH')

for prices in price:
    print(prices.text)
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 0):

Переделаю слегка код из вопроса:

```python
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = requests.get('https://minfin.com.ua/currency/crypto/')
soup = BeautifulSoup(url.content, 'html.parser')
names = soup.findAll('div', class_='sc-18qu8it-11 hZgTBs')
prices = soup.findAll('div', class_='sc-18qu8it-3 fygJIH')
```

Теперь можно выводить с использованием [`str.format()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) и объединить два листа с помощью [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip):

```python
for name, price in zip(names, prices):
    print('{}: {}'.format(name.text, price.text))
```

либо просто пройтись по всем индексам в паре:

```python
for i in range(len(names)):
    print('{}: {}'.format(names[i].text, prices[i].text))
```

###### Вывод:

```
Bitcoin: 20.884,00 $
Ethereum: 1.552,64 $
Tether: 0,999608 $
BNB: 310,56 $
...
Decentraland: 0,566351 $
Frax: 0,999842 $
MultiversX: 42,12 $
Tezos: 1,029 $
```

Comment: `for pair in zip(names, prices):` -> `for name, price in zip(names, prices):`